# How to convert the result of evalmetrics C3.ai COVID-19 API to pandas dataframe for easier analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the C3.ai's APIs for analyzing unified COVID-19 data. For generating a time series of confirmed cases and deaths across locations of COVID outbreaks, I successfully called the `evalMetrics` API, but the response received is `JSON`.

How can I best convert this to a pandas dataframe in python so that I can easily perform my analyses on this data?

Here is the code I have used to call the `evalMetrics` API successfully:

```
import json, requests
locations_to_evaluate = ["China","Italy"]
expressions_to_evaluate = ["JHU_ConfirmedCases","JHU_ConfirmedDeaths"]
url = "https://api.c3.ai/covid/api/1/outbreaklocation/evalmetrics/"
request_data = {
    "spec": {
        "ids": locations_to_evaluate,
        "expressions": expressions_to_evaluate,
        "start": "2020-02-01",
        "end": "2020-03-01",
        "interval": "DAY"
    }
}
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
response = requests.post(url=url, json=request_data, headers=headers)
eval_metrics_result = json.loads(response.text)
```

I want to convert `eval_metrics_result` to a pandas dataframe. Is there a generic function I can use to convert any `eval_metrics_result` to a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
def convert_evalMetrics_to_Pandas(eval_metrics_result):
    evaluate_ids = list(eval_metrics_result["result"].keys())
    evaluate_metrics = list(eval_metrics_result["result"][evaluate_ids[0]].keys())
    timestamps = eval_metrics_result["result"][evaluate_ids[0]][evaluate_metrics[0]]["dates"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns = ["Evaluate_ID"]+evaluate_metrics,
        index = ["{}#{}".format(evaluate_id,timestamp) for evaluate_id in evaluate_ids for timestamp in timestamps]
    )
    df["Evaluate_ID"] = df.index.str.split("#").str[0]
    for evaluate_id in evaluate_ids:
        for evaluate_metric in evaluate_metrics:
            df[evaluate_metric].loc[df["Evaluate_ID"]==evaluate_id] = eval_metrics_result["result"][evaluate_id][evaluate_metric]["data"]
    df.drop("Evaluate_ID", axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df
```

Note that in this case, the index of the dataframe will be in the format: `id#timestamp`
The timestamps for one `id` will be ordered before the dataframe index moves on to the next `id` for the same timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other ways to store / grab as a dataframe:

1. Wide format with evaluate_id, expression, dates array, data array.

```
import pandas as pd

# get as a wide df with evaluate_id, expression, dates array, data array
evaluate_ids = list(eval_metrics_result['result'].keys())
expressions  = list(eval_metrics_result['result'][evaluate_ids[0]].keys())
formatted_list = [{'evaluate_id':evaluate_id,
                  'expression':expression, 
                  'dates': pd.to_datetime(eval_metrics_result['result'][evaluate_id][expression]['dates']),
                  'data': eval_metrics_result['result'][evaluate_id][expression]['data']} 
                                          for evaluate_id in evaluate_ids for expression in expressions]
wide_df = pd.DataFrame(formatted_list)
```

2. Long format - basically the same as Suraj's but instead, evaluate_id and expression are stored in their own own columns. This helps the df play well with groupby.

```
# convert from wide to long format
wide_df['dates-data'] = wide_df.apply(lambda row: zip(row['dates'], row['data']), axis = 1)
wide_df.drop(columns = ['dates', 'data'])

def wide2long(df, list_col):
    a = pd.DataFrame(df[list_col].tolist()).stack().reset_index(level = 1, drop = True).rename(list_col)
    return df.drop(list_col, axis = 1).join(a).reset_index(drop = True)[df.columns]

long_df              = wide2long(wide_df, 'dates-data')
long_df['date']      = long_df['dates-data'].apply(lambda date_data: date_data[0])
long_df['data']      = long_df['dates-data'].apply(lambda date_data: date_data[1])
long_df.drop(columns = ['dates-data'], inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [c3covid19](https://github.com/connor-makowski/c3covid19) with [docs here](https://connor-makowski.github.io/c3covid19/api.html). Its a simple c3 covid19 data lake connection wrapper for python.

Install

```
pip install c3covid19
```

Run

```
from c3covid19 import c3api

cnx=c3api()

locations_to_evaluate = ["China","Italy"]
expressions_to_evaluate = ["JHU_ConfirmedCases","JHU_ConfirmedDeaths"]
request_data = {
    "spec": {
        "ids": locations_to_evaluate,
        "expressions": expressions_to_evaluate,
        "start": "2020-02-01",
        "end": "2020-03-01",
        "interval": "DAY"
    }
}

output_df=cnx.request(
    data_type='outbreaklocation', 
    parameters=request_data, 
    api='evalmetrics', 
    output_type='pd'
)
```

This is a simple conversion to pandas though. It works great with a list of dictionaries, but struggles with a more nested structure. You should probably be converting to a properly formatted pandas df.

Instead, use the following to get a dictionary:

```
output_df=cnx.request(
    data_type='outbreaklocation', 
    parameters=request_data, 
    api='evalmetrics',
    output_type='objs'
)
```

Then follow the directions listed on on one of the more targeted time series answers by Suraj or Jac.